# Programa básico de reconocimiento de voz en Raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, telegram, raspberry

Me pidieron realizar un script que reconozca ciertas palabras enviando notas de voz via Telegram, todo esto en una Raspberry Pi 4 y haciendo uso de Python.

Ya hice mi bot con BotFather y tengo nociones de la implementacion de la libreria de telebot pero no se que hacer para el reconocimiento de la voz.

¿Podrían ayudarme?

Comment: Hola Mario. tu proyecto esta interesante. Pero por favor, comparte lo que has intentado como codigo o, al menos, architectura

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es muy sencilla, veo que ya tienes una idea de lo que tienes que hacer está muy bien. Mira te proporciono este código base que te sirve para seguirlo expandiendo.

Solo asegurate de instalar las dependencias necesarias y agregar el token que obtienes al crear tu bot con BotFather. En este caso como dices se está haciendo uso de la librería telebot y además se está haciendo uso de SpeechRecognition. Para que el programa funcione adecuadamente debes estar conectado a internet.

Este es el código:

```
import telebot
import speech_recognition as sr
import subprocess
import os

TOKEN = 'COLOCA_TU_TOKEN'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

# Función para descargar y convertir la nota de voz
def download_and_convert_voice(message):
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.voice.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

    # Guardar el archivo OGG
    ogg_filename = "voice.ogg"
    with open(ogg_filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(downloaded_file)

    # Convertir OGG a WAV
    wav_filename = "voice.wav"
    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', ogg_filename, wav_filename])

    return wav_filename

# Función para transcribir la nota de voz
def transcribe_voice(filename):
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.AudioFile(filename) as source:
        audio_data = recognizer.record(source)
        try:
            text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio_data, language="es-ES")
            return text
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            return ""
        except sr.RequestError:
            return ""

# Manejador de mensajes de voz
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['voice'])
def handle_voice(message):
    wav_filename = download_and_convert_voice(message)
    transcript = transcribe_voice(wav_filename)

    if "prueba" in transcript.lower():
        bot.reply_to(message, "Mensaje recibido")
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Opción no válida")
    os.remove(wav_filename)  # Opcional: eliminar el archivo WAV después de su uso

# Iniciar el bot
bot.polling()
```

En este caso lo que hace este programa es que cuando envias una nota de voz en la que digas "prueba" el bot te responde con "Mensaje recibido" en cualquier otro caso te responde con "Opción no válida"

Comment: Muchas gracias, de verdad. Tu código es totalmente funcional y me sirve de base para realizar lo que me pidieron.

Comment: [es.so] no es un sitio al estilo _dame el código_ ("_gimme teh codez_"). Lee [answer], por sobre todo la sección _Contesta preguntas **bien formadas**_.